# how to download file on aws glacier without json format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

In AWS Glacier , when we initiate job, after 4+ hours we can download it, but download format is supported only json format, so how i can download my original files ? is it by using get-job-output or any other things ?

Comment: Yes you need to call "get-job-output". This is very clear in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when i use get-job-output, outfile show me a json file that contains archiveid,archive description etc., so i am unable to download regular file such as txt or others.

Comment: The documentation for `get-job-output` says: "the output will be either the content of an archive or a vault inventory". It sounds like you didn't create the correct type of job?